# I don't understand how require.js handles the load paths. Do I need to use require.config every time I define a module? 

Tags: javascript, amd

I am learning about require.js and think I am just missing something. I don't understand how it loads files.

I have my jquery file in a lib directory.

This does not work:

It shows that jquery is being loaded in the chrome network panel. Error is: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function . so it is basically saying that $ is undefined.

```
require(['lib/jquery'],function($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    alert('hello');
  });
});
```

This works:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'lib/jquery'
    }
});


require(['jquery'],function($) {
      $(document).ready(function(){
      alert('hello');
    });

});
```

In other examples I see online you don't have to set the paths with require.config. Do I have to do this every time that I want to define a module? I know I am using require and not define in this case, but I am having the same issue with the define method. Every time I make a module using define I have to set the paths using require.config(). I think I am missing something here. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to reflect comments and [James' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11752596/781):

You have two problems:

1. jQuery, for the reasons James outlines in his answer, requires that you either have `paths` set in your config, or that you, in the code you've outlined, set `baseUrl` to "lib".
2. you have to remember that you can't just load any old script with RequireJS. Only scripts that conform to the AMD standard can be loaded.

Having said this, I'd advice you use [require-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11752596/781) instead.

You'll probably end up using jQuery plugins that will assume jQuery is loaded on the page, and those won't work with the approach you're trying.

Comment: Yeah, I read that, but I feel uneasy using that because I am not sure where it is getting jquery from and what version it is grabbing. I would rather host the file myself. Also, I am using other libraries and am mainly confused about how the paths are being loaded. I have the same issue loading underscore.js

Comment: @SpencerCooley RequireJS doesn't support underscorejs out of the box. You have to remember arbitrary scripts can't be loaded in RequireJS. Only scripts the the AMD format can be required. There's tricks to load underscore, so my guess is that you do understand how paths are loaded, you just haven't tried to load a script that can actually be loaded.

Comment: looks like it is AMDified at the end 

  // AMD define happens at the end for compatibility with AMD loaders
  // that don't enforce next-turn semantics on modules.
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define('underscore', function() {
      return _;
    });
  }

Answer (score 2):

This is a constraint on the AMD registration done by jquery. It explicitly registers as a named module called 'jquery' so you must have a paths config in for it, or in the case above, set baseUrl to be 'lib' then you do not need the paths config.

Other libraries normally should use an anonymous module registration, so you should not need to do a paths config for every library. [More details here](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Updating-existing-libraries#wiki-anon).

Also, some libraries, like underscore, do not call define() directly, but you can get a level of support by using the [shim config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim).

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, from what I understand, if a module does not have a specified module id then it is anonymous and it can be called by just specifying the path require(['lib/this','lib/that']). If it does have an id, as jquery does, then the path will need to be set first with require.config